# Runtime.ImportModuleError unable to import module cannot import module name "DEPRECETED_SERVICE_NAMES" from botocore.docs

Tags: python, aws-lambda, boto3, botocore

I am running my Python code of Lambda runtime Python3.9 and recently I made some changes in the code and deployed those changes, after deploying the changes I am now getting an error saying "cannot import module name "DEPRECETED_SERVICE_NAMES" from botocore.docs". After reverting to the runtime version code is running fine but it is just a temporary fix, what is the permanent solution for this?